# Edit one single entity from multiple bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle

I have a `Bundle` which is the core of my website (we will name it `CoreBundle`).

But my website will be share and need to be modulable.

For example, I have an entity `CoreApplication` :

- id
- attr1
- attr2

But now, I need to add 2 independent Bundle (part1 / part2) to the core, which will be added to the core depends on what the company needs. Both parts will do the same thing: add fields to Application.

For example, the company could install only part1. Or only part2. Or part1 and part2.

That's why I don't know how to start.
I could create one Bundle for each part and `extends` the Core. But if I add part1Bundle and part2Bundle, this will not work?
I could create an `Interface` InterfaceApplication and use `resolve_target_entities`...

How would you do?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't do anything with extending bundles as that functionality goes away in S4.  resolve_target_entities might be a solution but unfortunately your question did not translate well to English so it is difficult to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

This has been done before by OROCRM. Although I would try to avoid going that route unless it is your last resort.

How it works:

1. You create your bundles
2. Your bundle has doctrine migrations that updates the database schema
3. The entities gets populated from the database schema

Documentation:

https://oroinc.com/doc/orocrm/2.0/cookbook/entities/adding-properties

https://oroinc.com/doc/orocrm/2.0/book/entities

EntityExtendBundle Source code:

https://github.com/oroinc/platform/tree/master/src/Oro/Bundle/EntityExtendBundle